# How to replace column in a dynamically-named data frame in R

Tags: r, stringr

I'm working on some stuff for my fantasy football league.  I populate a series of data frames, each named for the position (e.g., QB for quarterbacks, RB for running backs, etc.)

I've been able to use the apply() function to do a lot with rbinding the separate chunks of a position into a single dataframe, but what I'd really like to do is to strip out some text from something for each position.

So I have a dataframe named QB, and one of the columns is called Player, that has some superfluous text I'd like to remove.

So, if I were to do this, it works:

```
thePosNick <- "QB"
thePlayer <- paste(thePosNick, "$Player", sep="")
g <- str_replace(eval(parse(text=thePlayer)), "remove this text", "")
g <- str_replace(g, "more meaningless text", "")
g <- str_trim(g)
#expected behavior:
QB$Player <- g
```

That works fine, however, I'd love to be able to do this dynamically, and doing the following doesn't seem to work:

```
thePosNick <- "QB"
thePlayer <- paste(thePosNick, "$Player", sep="")
g <- str_replace(eval(parse(text=thePlayer)), "remove this text", "")
g <- str_replace(g, "more meaningless text", "")
g <- str_trim(g)
#but i'd love to be able to do something like this:
assign(thePlayer, value=g)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is it the same text for each player? You could look at `gsub`. It would also help a lot if you created a small set of example data to illustrate the input and output.

Comment: Make your life easier and put all of your data.frames in a list. You can then use convenient tools like `lapply` and don't need the `assign`/`get`/`eval(parse())` nightmare.

Answer (score 4):

First, I'd make a function to do your fixing.

```
fixit <- function(g) {
  g <- str_replace(g, "remove this text", "")
  g <- str_replace(g, "more meaningless text", "")
  g <- str_trim(g)
  g
}
```

Then `get` the variable you want, fix it, and `assign` back.

```
thePosNick <- "QB"
x <- get(thePosNick)
x$Player <- fixit(x$Player)
assign(thePosNick, x)
```

Alternatively, a more R idiomatic way would be to use a list to store all your positions instead of just storing them in the global environment.  Then you could use lapply to fix them all at once.

```
positions <- list(QB=QB, RB=RB, TE=TE)
positions <- lapply(positions, function(x) { x$Player <- fixit(x$Player) } )
```

Answer (score 3):

Store your stuff like this?

```
biglist = list(QB=list(Player='yo remove this text here'))

# $QB
# $QB$Player
# [1] "yo remove this text here"
```

Then

```
g <- biglist[[thePosNick]][['Player']]
biglist[[thePosNick]][['Player']] <- str_replace(g, "remove this text", "")

# $QB
# $QB$Player
# [1] "yo  here"
```

That is, you can put names of things inside `[[]]`. You're only encountering trouble assigning to stuff in the global environment (as opposed to nested in a list), I reckon.

*Comment.* As @Roland said, you'd be better of yet storing this in a data.frame or data.table, perhaps with one row per player: `DF <- data.frame(Player='You',Pos='QB',Team='Youse',...)`

Answer (score 1):

You must use

```
eval(parse(text=paste(thePlayer,"<-",deparse(g))))
```

instead of `assign(thePlayer, value=g)`.

Why? Because `QB$Player <- g` is not a direct assignment, but a call to the function `'$<-'`, which places the value in `g` in a special position of the object `QB`. There is no object `QB$Player` in your environment, that is why `assign()` fails.

Opinion:

This is all pretty bad because the better solution is to use a list of dataframes like this:

```
L <- list(QB=QB, RB=RB, ...)

g <- str_replace(L[["QB"]]$Player, "remove this text", "")
g <- str_replace(g, "more meaningless text", "")
g <- str_trim(g)
L[["QB"]]$Player <- g
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick and dirty solution would be

```
eval(parse(text=paste(thePlayer,"<-g",sep="")))
```

I can't help but think, though, manipulating these objects by their names as strings might not be the cleanest way to go about this whole problem.

Comment: That's why I called it "quick and dirty".  The `eval(parse())` structure is also used in the original question.